# How to assign variables without displaying?

Tags: mysql, select

Below is a really scaled down version of my SELECT statement.

```
SELECT
  start_date,
  IFNULL(@stop_date := HAIRY_CALCULATION(this_date, that_date)), '') as stop_date,
  IF(@stop_date = '', 0, DATEDIFF(@stop_date, start_date)) as elapsed_days
FROM mytable
```

I'd like to put the `elapsed_days` as the second column, but it depends on the existence of the `@stop_date` variable.

How could I do something like below where I'm assigning the variable without displaying so I can use the variable later in the column calculations?

```
SELECT
  DO_NOT_DISPLAY(@stop_date := IFNULL(HAIRY_CALCULATION(this_date, that_date), '')),
  start_date,
  IF(@stop_date = '', 0, DATEDIFF(@stop_date, start_date)) as elapsed_days,
  @stop_date as stop_date
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one work around. Maybe not the best, but:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
-- -------- The following are just variable assignments for later use; they're not displayed in this column.
    SUBSTRING(
      (@stop_date := IFNULL(HAIRY_CALCULATION(this_date, that_date), '')),
      0
    ),
-- -------- end of variable assignments for later use
    start_date
  ) as start_date,
  IF(@stop_date = '', 0, DATEDIFF(@stop_date, start_date)) as elapsed_days,
  @stop_date as stop_date
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Anyone see any dangers or bad practice in using this approach?

Comment: It's crazy voodoo and I'd strongly advise against this.

Comment: It's clearly unorthodox. But it is readable, and it only goes through the data set one time. Other than lack of orthodoxy, any other objections?

Comment: I'd argue it's not readable, it makes no sense, and it's bound to cause problems later. If this was the only way to solve the problem, which it isn't, I'd put a short note apologizing for it in the code just in case someone else stumbles upon it and is immediately tempted to try and excise it.

Comment: Thanks, @tadman. I wish there were a way to assign variables in the `SELECT` statement this way, perhaps using a NO_COLUMN keyword or something. However, for now, given the size of the table, the trade-off for only going through the data is worth it. Anyone else have warnings or suggestions?

Comment: That's just not how SQL works. If you want to strip things from result sets or add on things then you wrap them in another `SELECT` that does the manipulation. Honestly, I think you're causing a huge fuss over nothing here. Just ignore the column when you're fetching this. Throw it out. Your server won't care.

Comment: Thanks, @tadman. Just considering options. Anyone else have comments, warning, suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can always `SELECT` from a `SELECT` to narrow down what data you want to propagate:

```
SELECT stop_date, elapsed_days FROM
  (SELECT
    start_date,
    IFNULL(@stop_date := HAIRY_CALCULATION(this_date, that_date)), '') as stop_date,
    IF(@stop_date = '', 0, DATEDIFF(@stop_date, start_date)) as elapsed_days
  FROM mytable) as subset
```

Note nothing is ever "displayed" except by your client. You're talking about manipulating what ends up in your result sets.

If this is something you're doing frequently and the logic behind it is unlikely to change arbitrarily you might want to wrap this up in a view so you can do something like:

```
SELECT stop_date, elapsed_days FROM mytable_hairy_view
```

**Edit**: Here's a possible two-pass approach:

```
SELECT
  start_date,
  IF(stop_date = '', 0, DATEDIFF(stop_date, start_date)) AS elapsed_days
  FROM
    (SELECT
      start_date,
      HAIRY_CALCULATION(this_date, that_date) AS stop_date
      FROM mytable) as stop_dates
```

Comment: Yes, but the value of `@stop_date` changes with each row. How to get around that?

Comment: Instead of using a variable, why not compute only `stop_date` in the inner `SELECT` and then expand that as necessary on the outside?

Comment: I'm a real newbie for inner selects. Can you give an example?

Comment: Edited to add an example. Just think of the inner `SELECT` as an intermediate form. You can build up your final structure incrementally.

Comment: Thanks for the updated example. The only thing I don't like about this approach is that it goes through the data twice. My table is quite large.

Comment: It goes through the raw data once and a temporary table once. It probably won't be that bad in practice, but give it a shot and see how it performs. If you're really stuck, make a view that does the "hairy calculation" part and select against that. A view acts as a macro and helps the query optimizer.